# plot data by grouping

Tags: plotting

This must be simple, but I cannot seem to figure it or find the solution anywhere. I have data in 1000s of rows and 3 columns. Every thousands of rows have a unique tag id in the first column. I want to plot the 3rd column with the 2rd column as the x-axis with separate line for each tag id. I do the following, but how do I plot each line with a different color depending on the tagid and show the tagids at the end of each line on the top?

```
p = DeleteDuplicates[s\[Transpose][[1]]]
ListPlot[s[[All, {2, 3}]],{PlotLegends -> p}]
```

I suspect the problem is due to `All` in the `ListPlot`, but do not know a way around

Sample data can be found [here](https://github.com/bhargavarama/data/blob/master/SampleData.csv).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import = Import["SampleData.csv", "CSV"];

import = {1, 10^-9, 1} # & /@ import
```

The second line is to rescale the x values for clarity of the plot.

```
ids = DeleteDuplicates[import[[All, 1]]]
```

> {15, 17, 39, 50, 53, 59, 75}

```
data = GatherBy[import, First];

s = data[[All, All, {2, 3}]];

ListLinePlot[s, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> ids, FrameLabel -> {"x [10^9]", Rotate["y", 270 Degree]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex. Use `GroupBy`, instead, e.g. `GroupBy[data, ToString[First[#]] & -> ({10^-9, 1} Rest[#] &)]`. `ListLinePlot` will pick up the keys (now strings) automatically, and use them as legend labels. This reduces it to a one liner.